# Add attachment to SOAP message in Custom Mediator, WSO2 ESB

Tags: java, soap, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I am trying to implement a custom mediator in WSO2 ESB and what I am trying to achieve is that the mediator must take the file path as input and then add it to the SOAP message as an attachment.

The mediator code I have written so far, gets the attachment path and prints the SOAP message. Now I have skimmed through the documentation of [MessageContext](https://synapse.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/synapse/MessageContext.html) interface and I can see that we can add/remove elements to SOAP message, etc but I can not figure out how to add attachment in the SOAP message. Any ideas?

```
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPBody;
import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext; 
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

public class SoapModifier extends AbstractMediator { 

private String AttachmentFilePath;  

public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
    context.setDoingSWA(true);
    FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(AttachmentFilePath);
    SOAPBody soapBody = context.getEnvelope().getBody();
    System.out.println("Message Being Processed : " + context.toString());
    return true;
}

public String getAttachmentFilePath(){
    return AttachmentFilePath;
}

public void setAttachmentFilePath(String path){
    AttachmentFilePath = path;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help 
[Attachments API in Apache Axis2](http://wso2.com/library/1148/)

Comment: Thanks!
The article suggests using the Message Context interface of Apache Axis 2 but the custom mediator gives in the Message Context object of Apache Synapse.
So I solved it by casting the message context to Apache Axis 2.

Comment: So the code addition will be like that:
`DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(fileDataSource);
 org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext mc = ((Axis2MessageContext) context).getAxis2MessageContext();
String contentid = mc.addAttachment(dataHandler);`